Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server - set log_statement for specific user only
Is there any way to set log_statement for specific user in Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server?
Normally it should be like: ALTER ROLE user_login SET log_statement TO 'all'; but due to access restriction on flexible server I got: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_statement".

Who were you logged in as at the time?


According to this

Only superusers can change this setting.

If you try with any other instead of superuser then you may get above error. But According to the MS document
super user is not accessible is not accessible in azure PostgreSQL - Flexible Server. You can enable log_statement server parameter by following below procedure:
Go to Server parameters search for log_statement select the required value as shown below:

After Selecting the value save the changes by clicking on Save.  Then you can view the logs in monitoring section. For more information you can refer to the MS document.
